# Stack overflow when trying to initialize two fixed size cubes

Tags: armadillo

```
#include <armadillo>

int main()
{
    arma::cube::fixed<28, 28, 100> a;
    arma::cube::fixed<28, 28, 100> b;
}
```

This code is giving me the following error

> Unhandled exception at 0x000000013F6034A7 in mnist.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000133000).

Any ideas why? Cause I'm clueless.

Answer (score 0):

Use of [fixed size matrices](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_mat) or cubes is only recommended for very small sizes, as stack size is limited. In your case, 28*28*100*8 = 627200, or about 612 Kb. (The last 8 is the number of bytes taken up by a double precision floating point number). There is also some overhead due to internal matrix and cube house keeping.

Instead of using fixed size cubes, you would be better off using standard cubes:

```
arma::cube a(28,28,100);
```